# Need help centering a table inside a div container

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I'm making the game dots and boxes for a college project, but I can't figure out how to center the game table on my screen. 
[This is how it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzj3n.jpg)

The table and the form are inside a `container-fluid` div.

```
form#difficulty {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}


table#tableid { 
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: 0px;
}
```

I've searched for hours but nothing seems to work, I'm very frustrated and don't know what else to do, tried everything I found and nothing worked... How do I keep the table always centered on the window regardless of its size? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We need all your code, not just a snippet of two elements. Can you copy/paste it into a working JSFiddle?

Comment: The first rule of centering is *"Don't use floats"*

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting this as you having two columns, a side-bar on the left and a main column on the right of it, in which the table lives.

What I've done is show you how to have two columns and center the table in the larger second column.

https://jsfiddle.net/1v0L7x5j/

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For column_wrapper:

```
column_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For columns:

```
.col1{
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
}

.col2{
   margin-left: 30%;
}
```